# Apple Application Submission Process

Tags: ios

Hi I am getting into the final steps of developing my app and I am starting to worry about wether or not my app will meet Apple's standards.  I am worried about a feature that my app has that allows users to get directions to certain events by clicking a button and having the Apple Maps App open and give the user directions.  Is this ok? 
Thanks

Comment: shouldnt be a problem, easiest is to just submit it for review and see what they say, if they say no you are going to have to change it anyway so might as well just submit (if your app is ready)

Comment: This question is off topic because it is about Apple Store listing policies, not programming.

Comment: Yes, submit your build and wait for the review, if somethings is not according to apple standard, they will reject it and they will give u an explanation about that.
Best of luck for your application.

Comment: @Fonix That should be the answer, not a comment

Comment: @krumelur, its not a very definitive answer, but ok ill put it as an answer

Comment: @Fonix  Thanks for the advice.  Im only worried because I have heard a lot of really bad experiences with submissions and I'm just trying to make everything as perfect as possible so that I don't get rejected since I have put SO MUCH TIME into my project.  I heard about one app that got rejected just because the reviewer didn't understand the purpose of the app.  That's a pretty dumb reason if you ask me.

Comment: @Fonix No it is not, nor is it possible for anyone outside of Apple to give. But unless what the OP asks is clearly a violation, it's the best anyone on SO can do IMHO.

Comment: @TripPhillips i would take a look through the [review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) and maybe more specifically then [location based guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#location)

Comment: @Fonix I will look through it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Paul Im just trying to get help from other programmers who may have advice and can help me.  I don't see how this is off topic since the ultimate goal of most programming projects is to get it out to other users and submit it.  It's not like I asked a question about how to tie my shoes.  That is off topic.

Comment: @TripPhillips i would agree its probably a bit off topic for stackoverflow, since its meant for coding questions specifically, it may be more suited for [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com) for future reference

Comment: @TripPhillips Here's the latest meta Q&A for [Are questions about app-stores on-topic?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).  If you disagree with it or have a question, perhaps ask on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shouldnt be a problem, easiest is to just submit it for review and see what they say, if they say no you are going to have to change it anyway so might as well just submit (if your app is ready)